# Is it possible to determine when GPS has reached best possible accuracy?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, gps

I want to add a bit of warm up delay to my GPS tracking app so that the user has to wait a bit before being able to record its position. The purpose is that it is more important to have high accuracy than fast startup time. Is it possible to determine when the GPS is “done” loading? I have noticed that the first received locations is most often less accurate.

I could of course compare the accuracy of each received location against some defined limit but I don’t know if that works in all cases.

I fear that if I wait for the accuracy to be better than, say 15 m, it could deadlock some users which are in a location that never gets better accuracy than that.

Should I wait a set amount of time instead?

Should I start the gps as soon as possible in the app, even before the tracking part of the app is launched to warm up the gps?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but my gut reaction would be to measure the location multiple times and take some average of the values. There are pros and cons to mean, median, and mode in this specific example

Comment: I think what you need is not a programming answer, but a better understanding of how GPS works: the rising and setting of satellites; signal strength and distortion; delivery and timing of the almanacs. The [Wiipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) will give you a good grounding. This might even be a question for [gis.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems years ago. The location wasn't always accurate. We did a lot of research to fix the issue, our problem was that our users sometimes used the app inside big trading centers across the USA, where the GPS signal was low.

#### Packages

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-location-enabler

#### Best accuracy can be achieved when WiFi and GPS are turned ON.

We reported on our backend the location we're capturing and started switching implementations until we finally got the correct results.

##### react-native-location config

```
RNLocation.requestPermission({
    ios: 'whenInUse',
    android: {
        detail: 'fine'
    }
})

RNLocation.configure({
    distanceFilter: 50, //meters
    desiredAccuracy: {
        ios: 'best',
        android: 'highAccuracy'
    },
    // Android only
    androidProvider: 'auto',
    interval: 5000,
    fastestInterval: 10000,
    maxWaitTime: 5000
})
```

**After we subscribed for location updates we found that the 5th response was accurate enough so we waited until the event ping with location 5 times.**

##### react-native-android-location-enabler config

```
RNAndroidLocationEnabler.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded({
    interval: 10000,
    fastInterval: 5000
})
```

The flow must be executed in the following way.

1. Check permissions from react-native-location
2. Prompt for enabled location if needed // android only - w/o this the location wasn't that accurate.
3. Configure react-native-location and subscribe to location updates
4. Wait until the location updates pings 5 times with the user's location

   ```
   let subscription = RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(
       (locations) => {
   })
   ```

**I hope this can help you! Good luck!**